# Display log4j output in dialog

Tags: java, log4j

I am trying to have a dialog window display log4j output.

I found [LogFactor5Dialog](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/org/apache/log4j/lf5/viewer/LogFactor5Dialog.java.html).

Is this what this is intended for?

If so, how do I configure it?

Comment: You may can read the log messages from a SocketAppender. If not try to create your own appender extending the AbstractAppender class (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/AbstractAppender.html).

Answer (score 1):

On the [Apache API Javadoc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/lf5/viewer/LogFactor5InputDialog.html), LogFactor5InputDialog's purpose is described as:
Creates a popup input dialog box so that users can enter a URL to open a log file from.

So this is definitely not what you are looking for. I do look forward for other suggestions though.